# How to use JEST fn()?

Tags: jestjs

I can't get my head arround JEST function mocking.

My Setup:

I've an object I want to test. inside that Object I call a function, that wraps an external API call. I want to mock the 'getUser' function (not the #getUser ;-) ).

```
class MyNicelogin {
  constructor(bHardLogin=false) {
    ...
    this.#getUser(oLoginResponse);
    ...
  }
  async #getUser(oLoginResponse=null) {
    ...
    try {
      ...
      this.oUser = await getUser(this.#oLoginResponse.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken);
      ...
    } catch (e) {
      ...
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I expected it to work like this

```
  const MyNiceLogin = require('../Website/js/MyNiceLogin.js');
  const mockGetUser = jest.fn(() => {return 'true';});
  getUser() = mockGetUser;

  ...

  describe('Test 1', () => {
    test('not logged in user on soft login => not relayed to login page', () => {
      ...
        new MyNiceLogin.MyNiceLogin(true);
        expect(sessionStorage.getItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      ...
    });
  });

  ...
```

but it errors with

```
  getUser() = mockGetUser;
  ^
  Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression.
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong with setting up the mock. Any idea, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The part in "new" is working:

old

const mockGetUser = jest.fn(() => {return 'true';});
getUser() = mockGetUser;

new

global.getUser = jest.fn(() => {return 'true';});